# Get Administrator's privileges in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, uac

Since I've installed Windows 8.1 I get lots of "Run-as-Administrator-troubles". I have to run anything as administrator to get it working. Though, there are things that do not work even that way.

Disabling the UAC doesn't work in Windows 8, so to run some applications I have to switch the user to Administrator.

Is there any way to give my user account administrative privileges?

Comment: Sure.  You do it the same way you do it in Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows XP and modify the which user group the user is in.  But you shouldn't have to run 99% of software as an Administrator its also not safe to always be logged in as an Administrator.  Most exploits can't be used if you don't have Administrator permissions.  What have you tried exactly?

Comment: This could be an issue with a virus that injected itself into a vital system component and is constantly asking for elevated privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recommend this<sup>1</sup>, but since the usual way isn't working, and if you don't mind being at risk, then you could try the following:

1. Open Powershell (as an admin)
2. Enter `Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "EnableLUA" -Value "0"`

<sup>1</sup> I do not recommend this approach because setting EnableLUA to false (`0`) prevents Windows from notifying you that an app is installing or trying to make changes to the computer. This can be a bad thing, because you don't really know what it may be installing, or trying to change (it could be trying to change registry settings that could have a negative impact on your system - or it could be copying viruses/Trojans to disk, or installing a keylogger, etc).

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715520.aspx).

Comment: please, explain me why this is not recommended?

Comment: @Victor Sure thing, give me a moment while I update my answer to include that info.

Comment: @Victor my pleasure. :)

Comment: In previous versions of Windows I had UAC completely disabled. I have antivirus software though.

Comment: Yeah, that's cool. So long as you have a good anti-virus + firewall program and don't download crazy looking stuff you should be all good.